# Target first level <li>s and not the nested <li>s

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>C
    <ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery, how do I target the FIRST level of `<li>`s?

For example, I need to make the font bold on hover to the `<li>`s with the letters A, B and C, but NOT have that font style applied to the nested `<li>`s (with the name *subsections*).

Here's an initial jsfiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNcsD/) if you'd like to use it.

Thanks.

**EDIT--**

**Solution:**

**CHILD SELECTORS**, that's the answer.

No need for jQuery, this can be done using CSS.

Here's the updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNcsD/1/)

**EDIT--** Here's a **[more clear demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNcsD/166/)**

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting only first-level elements in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Have a container `<div>` with a class, and use the `>` selector. Lets say your container div's class is "myclass":

```
.myclass ul li {
   ...this will affect both levels of li.
}

.myclass > ul > li {
   ...this will only affect the first level.
}

.myclass > ul > li > ul > li {
   ...this will only affect the second level.
}
```

Note: the `>` selector does not work in IE6 and below when used as a CSS selector. It does work in all other browsers though, including IE7 and IE8, and when used in JQuery, it works in all browsers supported by jQuery, including IE6.

Comment: Or without adding that container, use `body`: `$('body > ul > li').css('border', '1px solid red');`

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, and the same solution I came up with on my own. I selected this solution as the right answer because it doesn't need to use JavaScript to accomplish that, but I hadn't figured out it could be done with CSS only before posting the question. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that some CSS attributes may `inherit` so if you set the `.myclass > ul > li {font-size: 2em;}` then all your `li`s may still be affected unless you `.myclass li {font-size: 1em;}` as your default

Answer (score 20):

You could do this:

```
$('ul > li:not(:has(ul))');
```

But it would be better to give your top level `<ul>` an ID so you can target it with a valid CSS selector:

```
$('#topUL > li')
```

Comment: Your solution would only work if only one ´ul´ was used in the page and not if you would have several ´ul´s. Yet, your solution works nevertheless for this specific example. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo: Do you mean because of the ID? Yes you're right, you'd need to use a class instead to target the first level `<li>` elements across several top level `<ul>` elements at the same time. Or use the [`multiple-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) with the different IDs.

Comment: As of Mar 2023, `:has()` is now [valid and mostly available CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#specifications), but your first solution selects `<li>`s of any level which do not contain `<ul>`s.

Answer (score 11):

**CHILD SELECTORS**, that's the answer.

No need for jQuery, this can be done using CSS. Target the first-level `li` elements with a selector:

```
ul > li {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And then undo the styling for deeper `li` elements:

```
ul > li li {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here's the updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNcsD/1/).

Comment: That was my initial thought, too. It's hard to say if the OP needs some other (non-CSS) behavior too, that isn't captured in the hypothetical example.

Comment: looks as though your code has been applied to all elements in FF 17

Comment: @JamieHutber, The solution works on `:hover`. Here, I created a [more clear Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNcsD/166/)

Comment: this one is what im problem was, very hard to understand why the bold is applied to the second level if you have just the first CSS `ul > li { font-weight: bold;}`

Comment: @Seabizkit The font is bolded in all `li`s but since I only want the second-level `li`s bolded I have to "unbold" them by applying the second rule `ul > li li { font-weight: normal; }`.

Makes sense?

Comment: @RicardoZea i understand you have to do it! what i don't understand is  `CLASS.UL > li` why does this targets all `li`'s hope that clears up my confusion. when you have specifically targeted fir li ONLY.

Comment: @Seabizkit There's no class selector, I'm using an element selector. Plus `ul > li {…}` targets all first child `<li>`s in the document because we're using the child selector `>`, which really is the same thing as just doing `li {…}`, after all, all `li`s are first children anyway. The trick is in the second rule that negates what the first rule did. But you already knew that . Does that answer your question?

Comment: Mine has a class selector and still doesn't work.  i.e. i can understand why `ul > li` on its own may not work but don't understand why `CLASS.UL > li` is not honored mmm maybe the correct thing I'm looking for is 'CLASS >UL > li' ill try that, that should work. then it would make sense.

Comment: If I understood correctly, yes, you can just add a class to the `<ul class="class-name">` and target from there as `.class-name li {…}`. I also noticed that your syntax is incorrect: instead of `class.ul > li` it should be `ul.class > li`. I have a feeling that that's what's causing your issues.

Comment: @Seabizkit Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830624/target-first-level-lis-and-not-the-nested-lis#comment52831394_4830672).

Answer (score 2):

I would set one rule to target all li elements and then another to override this that targets nested li elements.

```
li{font-weight:bold;}
ul ul li{font-weight:normal;}
```

Nested li elements would be normal weight and top level would be bold.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem has been completely addressed (although there has been some good attempts).  Your example problem deals with applying a style to a parent and preventing the child from inheriting the style -- which is a CSS problem.

You could target the list items by knowing the parent element (as some have noted). Then add a class on hover.

```
$('div > ul > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('myHover');
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('myHover');
});
```

And your CSS would have the class for the parent, and a negating style for the children:

```
.myHover { font-weight: bold; }
.myHover li { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is very good solution. However, I prefer not having to use jQuery (although at the moment of typing the question I hadn't figured out it could be done with CSS only). Gave you a vote though.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if you wanted to do something else in javascript, or simply add CSS styles.  The :hover pseudo class is definitely the way to go for just style changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extended version of user @Spudley's answer - with a snippet.

Might save some people some time.

```css
/* this will affect all levels of li */
.myclass ul li {
  color: red;
}


/* this will only affect level 1 */
.myclass>ul>li {
  color: green;
}


/* this will only affect level 2 */
.myclass>ul>li>ul>li {
  color: blue;
}


/* this will only affect level 3 */
.myclass>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li {
  color: aqua;
}


* {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <ul>
    <li>Level 1
      <ul>
        <li>Level 2
          <ul>
            <li>Level 3</li>
            <li>Level 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Level 2</li>
        <li>Level 2
          <ul>
            <li>Level 3</li>
            <li>Level 3</li>
            <li>Level 3
              <ul>
                <li>Level 4</li>
                <li>Level 4</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with either jQuery or CSS3 using `:not()` selector to check the parent of a list.
To prevent CSS properties from inheriting you could wrap an items' content with `<span>` or `<div>`.

```css
:not(li) > ul > li > span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Level 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Level 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Level 2</span></li>
      <li><span>Level 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Level 3</span></li>
          <li><span>Level 3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Level 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Level 1</span></li>
</ul>
```

Note that this method will only work if the elements are directly nested (i.e. when using a child combinator (`>`)), otherwise `:not()` will just [always match a random ancestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Using jQuery/JS for this is possible but clearly not necessary. This is a CSS-only solution (I mentioned this in my edit :]).

Now, using the `:not()` pseudo-class is an option but in my opinion it makes the solution too verbose, hence, a bit less scalable.

One thing FOR SURE I would never recommend, is to use extra markup for the sake of targeting. TBH, seeing those `<span>` s inside those list items makes me cringe ><, lol

Comment: @RicardoZea Not sure what do you mean by "too verbose", but **it checks exactly for what is wanted without adding any extra classes**. The final selector looks quite verbose in this case, but **in my case I was checking for nested classes**, so it only added one more selector.
As for extra markup, I don't like it as well, but you can't select bare text in CSS. That's what `<span>` is for and your accepted answer also adds an extra `<div>`. On the other hand, **overriding styles for nested elements looks like a dirty hack to me and causes code duplication**.

Comment: @EvgeKo423 Seems you do know what “verbose” means. Your solution is verbose with the use of `:not(pseudo)` class and the `span` selector. ESPECIALLY, the `span` selector. I could get around using the `:not(pseudo)` class, but NOT a chance with using the `span`, **especially** in the HTML. The accepted solution uses a wrapper, that's **ONE** element, whereas your solutions **requires** a `<span>` **IN EACH** `<li>`. That's also verbose. Overriding styles isn't pretty, but **it is not** a hack. Plus, it isn't a rare use of the principle. BTW, the accepted solution validates, a “hack” doesn't.

Comment: @RicardoZea OK, I've got your point. I just wanted to share my solution in general, I agree that it works not so well in this particular case.