# Select list item with jQuery without targeting sub list items

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to target specific top level list items with jQuery. However some of these list items also include nested lists of their own,which I want to ignore.

I found a stackoverflow question here [Target first level <li>s and not the nested <li>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830624/target-first-level-lis-and-not-the-nested-lis)
about this very topic but after enacting the solutions I'm still encountering the same issue.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li data-level="1">
      Upper List Item
      <ul>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-level="1">List item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div > ul > li[data-level=1]").each(function(index){
    console.log(index + ":" + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o4mw0gd8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are grabbing all text from inside the top level `<li>`'s.

Considering that sub-level `<li>`'s are inside of a top-level `<li>`, then the text of those is inside the top level `<li>`'s too...

## Solution 1:

You should put your text inside a `<span>` tag and it would be much easier to find the text inside those `<span>`/s inside top-level `<li>`'s!

## Solution 2:

Before grabbing the text of your `<li>`'s delete all `<ul>` elements inside it, so you would get only the text of the top level `<li>`'s

**JS**:

```
$("ul > li[data-level=1]").each(function(index) {
    var current = $(this).clone();
    current.find('ul').remove();
    console.log(index + ":" + current.text().trim() );
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o4mw0gd8/5/)

Comment: I don't have access to the actual content that's being produced (partially why I'm using jQuery in the first place to grab the list) which is why I can't really use solution 1. But solution 2 worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Some tricks.

```
$("div > ul > li[data-level=1]").each(function(index){
    console.log(this.childNodes.item(0).textContent);
});
```

Comment: It's a good solution if there is only one node of text. But it might not work if the html structure is more complex

Comment: True, but that could be easily solved with .innerHTML (in case a complex structure needed)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude child `ul` elements from selection using jquery [**.not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul > li[data-level=1]").each(function(index) {
     $(this).not("ul").css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-level="1">
    Upper List Item
    <ul>
      <li>Sub list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-level="1">List item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Aramil says - you taking the whole inner content, which include the nested *ul>li*:

```
 "Upper List Item
  <ul>
    <li>Sub list item</li>
  </ul>"
```

Bu you can solve it with substring like this:

```
 $(function(){
  $("li[data-level=1]").each(function(){
     var txt=this.innerHTML;//the whole text including the nested ul>li
      if(txt.indexOf("<")>-1)txt=txt.substring(txt.indexOf("<"),0);//cut from first tag if needed
     console.info(txt);//needed txt
   });
});
```