# How to Exclude Children <li> from CSS Styling

Tags: html, css

I'm using SharePoint Designer and I would like to apply a custom bullet on the parent `li` (Desc 1 and Desc 2) of my list, but what's happening is that it is being applied on all the list items including the children `li`. Can someone help me with it? how it should be done correctly in CSS? Thanks.

```css
.tab-content.content-show ul li {
    list-style-image: url(/img.png);
}

.tab-content.content-show ul li > li {
    list-style-image: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the direct children and not the grandchildren, you can use ">" as shown below

```
.tab-content.content-show div > ul > li {
    list-style-image: url(/img.png);
}
```

And no need for 2nd class.

here is the customized css:

```
.tab-content.content-show div > ul > li {
    background: url("https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/313-3131657_blue-bullets-icon-png-transparent-png.png") left center no-repeat;
    background-size:20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. Your CSS should look like this:

```css
.tab-content.content-show div > ul > li {
    list-style-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Child Selector (>) applies the CSS rules to the *direct children* of the particular element.

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830672/801544

Note I've used a gradient instead of an image just to show that it works, but you can use any image instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should use "**ul:first-child**" in css:

```css
.tab-content.content-show ul:first-child > li{
    list-style-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the HTML code? If yes I would put a class on the `li` you are interested in.

`<li class="custom-bullet">Desc 1</li>`

```
.custom-bullet {
   list-style-image: url(/img.png);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the <li> of the parent list items. Those lists are coming from the backend and are bulleted already. @Laxmana

Answer (score 0):

`.tab-content.content-show ul li > li` is going to match `li` elements that are children of `li` elements … which is not allowed in HTML.

Just use child combinators instead of descendant combinators in the first place.

```css
.tab-content.content-show > div > ul > li {
    list-style-image: url(http://placekitten.com/20/20);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="parent">Desc 1 </li>
      <ul>
        <li>details 1</li>
        <li>details 2</li>
        <li>details 3</li>
        <li>details 4</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="parent">Desc 2 </li>
      <ul>
        <li>details 1</li>
        <li>details 2</li>
        <li>details 3</li>
        <li>details 4</li>
      </ul>
    </ul><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not getting the custom bullet already. @Quentin

Comment: @Xev — I added a live demo which proves it *does*

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to give parent list items a class attribute and you style that class.

```css
li.parent {
  list-style-image: url(/img.png);
}

.tab-content.content-show ul li > li {
  list-style-image: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="parent">Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="parent">Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to do it that way but I don't have access to the <li> of the parent list items. Those lists are coming from the backend and are bulleted already.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tab-content.content-show ul li.parent {
  list-style-image: url(/img.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class='parent'>Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li class='parent'>Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would love to do it that way but I don't have access to the <li> of the parent list items. Those lists are coming from the backend and are bulleted already.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `css` to following way

```
.tab-content.content-show > Div >  ul > li {
   color:red;
 }
```

[see the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/7bhe65va/5/)

As well as you can set unique class both and  and set colors accessing that class like following

*.html*

```
    <div class="tab-content content-show" data-content-id="1" id="content-1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="Desc1">Desc 1 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="Desc2">Desc 2 </li>
            <ul>
                <li>details 1</li>
                <li>details 2</li>
                <li>details 3</li>
                <li>details 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

*.css*

```
.tab-content.content-show  .Desc1{
   color:red;
}

.tab-content.content-show  .Desc2{
   color:green;
}
```

[see the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/7bhe65va/4/)