# Css selector problem - children and parent? 

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wonder how I can select ONLY the top level "Mega Parent" in my example?

```
<li class="page_item parent"><a href="#"> Mega Parent</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item parent"><a href="#">Subparent</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I want only my top parent item "Mega Parent" to have e.g. a red color. 
What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery

Comment: @BrianFlanagan Completely different

Comment: What kind of `ul` contains the top-level `li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
.page_item.parent > a { color: red; }
.page_item.parent li > a { color: inherit; }
```

Or you could add an extra class to your megaparent's element, which sets an additional style.

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved while defining classes, not while addressing them. But if you can't define them, I'd just go different selector for the nested one to overwrite the default you apply to all elements

```
.page_item.parent a{ color:red; }

.page_item.parent ul.children .page_item.parent{ color:black;}
```

or any other kind of default styling, you could also just append the second selector to some other definition.

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses inheritance for certain values, you may been to set `color` manually on descendants to negate the inheritance.

See here for an explanation:

http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/