# how to using jquery to select filedsets that are not under a fieldset?

Tags: jquery, selector, fieldset

I have a webform, where fieldset contains fieldsets. I want to use jquery to select the  fieldsets that are not children? how can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fieldsets you want are a direct child of the form, try:

```
$('form > fieldset')
```

See the [jQuery Child Selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for more info

Comment: what about using find(), what is the parameter?

Comment: @david, `$('form').find('> fieldset')` or `$('form').children('fieldset')`

Comment: If neither of these work then that might mean the fieldsets you are trying to target aren't direct descendants of the form.  Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the direct descendent selector: `form > fieldset`.

Comment: what about using find(), what is the parameter?