# How to iterate through only top level <tr> tags of a table

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to iterate through only top level means child  tags of a table.Below is my HTML

```
 <table id="tab1">
         --->   <tr>
                   <td>
                   <table>
                         <tr><td></td></tr>
                         <tr><td></td></tr>
                   </table>
                   </td>
            </tr>
         --->   <tr><td></td></tr>
         --->   <tr><td></td></tr>
 </table>
```

If i iterate through all tr tags using the below code

```
  $('#tab1 tr').each(function()
  {
      // This will iterate through all the <tr>  ( 5 tags).. 
  });
```

But i want to iterate through the  s which i have mentioned with > mark.. You can use the below fiddle to put hands on
http://jsfiddle.net/AzJRp/1/

Comment: Same issue as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers will "correct" your HTML to include `<tbody>`:

```
<table id="tab1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- ... -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If possible, add the `<tbody>` to your HTML yourself and then you can reliably use:

```
$('#tab1 > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2CJ/

If you don't insert the `<tbody>` yourself, `$('#tab1 > tr')` would work in some browsers and others would require `$('#tab1 > tbody > tr')`. If you add the `<tbody>` yourself, you can use the same simple CSS selector everywhere.

Comment: Yes master.. I am glad to have your response.. The HTML is being generated by one of the Dirty tool we have..I cannot add <tbody> statically... That generates dirty HTML.. Otherwise can i wrap <tbody> to <table> content and proceed with your code...

Comment: @user1008575: First of all, I'm no one's master but thanks anyway. You should be able to insert the `<tbody>` if it isn't there though, just check `$('#tab1 > tbody').length` and then use `$('#tab1').wrapInner('<tbody>')` to add the `<tbody>` if `$('#tab1 > tbody').length` is zero. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above answers/comments, I understand that most browsers may add *tbody* tag. I don't think it is good idea to add *tbody* programmatically to make it work with the selector **'#tab1 > tbody > tr'**.

Better to use [Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to solve the issue. (I didn't test it. Hope somebody will test it and modify the answer or will add comment here.)

```
$('#tab1 > tbody > tr , #tab1 > tr').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$("#tab1 > tbody > tr").each(function(index, value) {
   //this iterates through only 3 elements.
});
```