# CSS to select top level of a ul

Tags: css, css-selectors

`li > ul > li` selects all `li` elements which are deeper than the first level of a `ul`.

`li` selects all li elements

`li:not(li > ul > li)` should select all `li` elements which are no deeper than the first level of a `ul`--that is, only first level elements--but it doesn't. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: `:not` only accepts [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Comment: @Lotuse: I added a link to the spec...

Comment: @Lotus: According to the spec, `:nth-child` is a pseudo class and therefore should be a simple selector.

Comment: Take a look at [this question][1].  See if it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery

Comment: @Lotus nth-child is a pseudo-class, hence a simple selector.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child

Comment: Your link or comment doesn't explain anything .. `nth-child` is a class selector not a simple selector

Comment: From @FelixKling link: "A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class."

Pseudo-classes = simple selectors, nth-child = pseudo-class = simple selector.

Comment: And even to that extent, despite you being wrong, if you were right that nth-child is a class selector, class selectors are also simple selectors, so if it were true, nth-child would still be a simple selector. ;)

So to answer your secondary question above...  Yes, nth-child is a simple-selector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason `li:not(li > ul > li)` does not work is because the `li > ul > li` is not a simple selector (as Felix Kling noted in the comments to your question).

The easiest way to get the top level is to give a class or id to the outer most `ul` and then do:

```
.ulClassNameOrID > li {}
```

However, the following gets what you desire also ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyLtC/6/)) as it does not select any `ul` that is a direct child of a previous `li` (so is not a sublist of the outer list):

```
:not(li) > ul > li {}
```

Comment: He want's to select the first level elements, not the top-most level.

Comment: @Michael: I understand "first-level" to be the list elements that are under the initial `ul` element and no deeper, which would be the "top-most level". If that is incorrect, then I need the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: @Michael: And besides that, the title to the question mentions the "top level" while the question itself states "first level," so I think I have interpreted the OP correctly.

Comment: @ScottS My comment was well before your edit ;).  You indeed have.

Comment: @Michael: My edit didn't change anything about the essence of my answer, it just offered a second (more generic, without class or id) solution. But I'm glad we have come to a consensus on what we believe the OP is asking (though he has not made a statement himself).

Comment: That’s a nice crafty solution. Re top vs first level: in any case to get the next level is easy enough once you’ve got the top.