# Selector to find first matching level of elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Having the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div><span class="node">Content1</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><span class="node">Content2</span></div>
    </li>
    <!-- but also: -->
    <li>
        <div><span class="node">Content3</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div><span class="node">Content on 2nd level</span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to select all `span` elements with the CSS class `node` which are on the *first* level of the hierarchy. How to do that without also matching the last span on level 2?

**Edit:** The `div` tags are just for demo purposes. They can change to span or even be nested within another div. I don't want to get a brittle CSS selector out of this (web testing), so I do not want to use direct child selectors. Furthermore, I cannot make changes to the HTML code myself.

Comment: What about overriding the applied rule for the 2nd level `.node`? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3Wney/

Comment: @HashemQolami: Good idea for CSS styling, however, for selecting elements in web testing this is not suitable :-)

Comment: Do you know in advance how many levels of content there will be? Or can there be an arbitrary number of levels > 2?

Comment: I guess my point is, as I mention in my answer, you will need to know a few things in advance about the HTML in order to construct a selector that will conform to that HTML. If there were a "closest descendant" selector, this would be made much easier, but unfortunately CSS selectors haven't advanced to that point yet.

Comment: I think this may help, checkout the answer to this question: 
[css-to-select-top-level-of-a-ul][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705064/css-to-select-top-level-of-a-ul

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start from the parent of the top-level `ul` and work your way down using child selectors. For example, assuming the parent element is identified by `#parent`:

```
#parent > ul > li > div > span.node
```

If the hierarchy of elements between the `li` and the `span.node` is not fixed, then things get a little more complicated. In order to avoid matching the inner `span.node` elements, you *will* need to make some assumptions about the markup, since a simple descendant selector like the following will always return every `span.node` since every nested list occurs as a descendant of your top-level `li` elements:

```
#parent > ul > li span.node
```

Comment: Really important to note the identifier of the parent element or there is no anchor point at the root for your selector.

Comment: @D.R.: I don't think it's as straightforward then. Let me think about it and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `>` selector:

```
#parent > ul > li  .node
```

Or, if you haven't parent id:

```
ul > li :not(ul) .node
```

Comment: This will still select the nested `<span>`'s

Comment: However, the inner structure also looks like `ul > li .node`. David is right.

Comment: This won't work either, because `div` is `:not(ul)` (and so is `li` for every nested list, for that matter).

Comment: @BoltClock this selects direct list then node but not list's ul node. Am I wrong?

Comment: @C-link Nepal: Consider `ul > li > div > ul > li > div > .node` - any of the two `div`s and the inner `li` will all match `:not(ul)`.

Comment: @BoltClock So, what's the problem? I think the OP wanted like that.

Comment: The OP only wants the topmost `.node`s. If the OP wanted all of them then the question would be too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Fix/Ammend your html code, simple is better.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pNWC/8/)

```
<div><span class="node test">Content2</span></div>
```

add 2 class names to your span

```
.node.test {
    color: red;
}
```

points to the right span

Comment: As I am web testing an existing application this is not a suitable solution for me. I cannot change the HTML myself.

Comment: @DavidBarker if the word "fix" was too much for you I apologise. But using 2 class names to point to something instead of something like `#parent > ul > li > div > span.node` in my book is much better.

Comment: @D.R. I did not know you had no access to the html, maybe put this in your question :)

Comment: Not really, polluting html with unnecessary class' in my book is bad.