# jQuery Selector only on first level not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-trigger

I have a simple list with a sublist

```
<div id="master">
<ul>
    <li><div>Trigger Me!</div></li>
    <li><div>Trigger Me!</div></li>
    <li><div>Trigger Me!</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Do NOT trigger me</div></li>
            <li><div>Do NOT trigger me</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd only like to call a function only if the user clicks on the list element on the first level, but **NOT** on the second.
Regarding to the documentation and google, the trick should be easy by using the ">" in the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#master").on("click", "ul > li", function (){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

But as you can see on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kQH4x/ it also fires the trigger, when clicking on the sub list items.

A simular problem with the answer on stackoverflow (See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/977891/1099519 ) doesn't seem to work for some reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also fires on the sublist because you don't specify which `ul` it should start from. The sublist has the same structure, so also qualifies for the selector.

To fix this, add the main lists parent element to the selector, so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div#master").on("click", ">ul>li>div", function (){
      alert($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kQH4x/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Don't have to use (document).ready every time.
- Why "on", just bind
  "click" and read when to use "on" [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> ```
>   $(function(){
>        $("div#master > ul>li>div").click(function (){
>           alert($(this).text());
>        });
>     });
> ```

Comment: It was a code snippet from a page that uses the "load" method for dynamic content, that's why I have to use the "on" event