# Select elements from first level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this ul li list:

```
<ul>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">B</a></li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">C</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">A1</a></li>
      <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">B1</a></li>
      <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">C1</a></li>
      <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">D1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">E</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to choose all "li" element from the first level.

In this example it will be:

```
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">B</a></li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">C</a></li>
  <li><div>Text</div><a href="#">E</a></li>
```

Trying to use:

```
  $('ul').children()
```

I get all "li" elements from the first level and second level.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's because you're matching all the `<ul>` elements, at any level. You have to identify the `<ul>` element you're interested in (e.g. through `id` or `class`) in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting only first-level elements in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: _"I need to choose all "li" element from the first level."_ - No, in your example you indicate that you want all first-level li elements that don't contain a ul, as compared to *all* first-level li elements. In any case, is there any reason why you can't give the ul in question an id or class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select `li` of `ul:first` which doesnot has a `ul` element as child.

```
$('ul:first').children('li:not(:has(ul))');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mbxcap5/)

Comment: Note that this only works for the html snippet shown. If that were part of a larger page with other ul elements above it then obviously [it wouldn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/9mbxcap5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code which will search for 1st ul and then all li's:
$('ul:first>li')

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the first ul and then call .children()

Answer (score 0):

try

`$('ul>li').css(//your doing//);`

This will select the `direct childs` of the `all ul tags` in your code.

If you want to acess specific `ul`, try givig it a `class` or `id`.

Answer (score -1):

You could change your selector to

```
$("'whatever element is above first level ul element' > ul > li")
```

Comment: But `ul` matches the 2nd-level lists, so this will get their `li`'s as well.

Comment: then include the tag above the first ul in your selector

Answer (score -1):

Give the external ul  a class:

```
<ul class="my_ul">
....
</ul>
```

and in jquery you an get them like:

```
  $('.my_ul').children()
```

EDIT: my first code was getting al children.

Comment: You gave them the same class, didn't you mean to give the class only to the outer one?